# componentWillRecieveProps on parent does not update the child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having an issue getting the Parent component `componentWillRecieveProps` to work on the child component.

If i put all the logic in one component, everything will **work fine**. However, i want the post items to be in a separate component.

The only prop that is being updated is

```
  myLikes={post.Likes.length}
```

**Posts.js**(Parent)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {GetPosts} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper:{
      margin: '20px 0px',
      padding:'20px'
    }
    , 
    wrapper:{
      padding:'0px 60px'
    }
}
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    loading: true,
    isEditing: false, 
    // likes:[]
  }
  componentWillMount(){
     this.props.GetPosts();

    // this.setState({
    //   loading:false
    // })

  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
      let hasNewLike = true ;
      if(prevState.posts !== this.state.posts && this.state.posts>0) {
        for(let index=0; index < nextProps.myPosts.length; index++) {
          if(nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length !== 
            prevState.posts[index].Likes.length) {
              hasNewLike = true;

          }
      }
    }
    if(hasNewLike) {
       this.setState({posts: nextProps.myPosts, loading:false}) // here we are updating the posts state if redux state has updated value of likes
    }
    console.log(nextProps.myPosts);

 }

  render() {
    const {loading} = this.state;
    const { myPosts} = this.props
    console.log(this.state.posts);
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  myPosts: state.post.posts,

})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
  GetPosts: () => dispatch( GetPosts())
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

**PostList.js** (Child)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost, postLike, UpdatePost,EditChange, getCount, DisableButton} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import _ from 'lodash';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: '',

        }
    } 
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }
    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;

        console.log(this.props.posts)
        // console.log(this.props.ourLikes);
        return (
          <div>
            {posts.map(post => (

              <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                <PostItem
                  myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                  myTitle={this.state.title}
                  editChange={this.onChange}
                  editForm={this.formEditing}
                  isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id}
                  removePost={this.removePost}
                  {...post}

                />
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    // ourLikes: state.post.likes // reducer likes 
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

Alternatively if everything was in one component, it will work

**Posts.js(all in one)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    DeletePost,
    postLike,
    UpdatePost,
    EditChange,
    getCount,
    DisableButton
} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import {GetPosts} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    wrapper: {
        padding: '0px 60px'
    }
}
class Posts extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        posts: [],
        title: '',
        loading: true,
        isEditing: false,
    }
  } 

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.GetPosts();
    }
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({title: e.target.value})
    }
    formEditing = (id) => () => {
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        let hasNewLike = true;
        if (prevState.posts && prevState.posts.length) {
            for (let index = 0; index < nextProps.myPosts.length; index++) {
                if (nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length !== prevState.posts[index].Likes.length) {
                    hasNewLike = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hasNewLike) {
            this.setState({posts: nextProps.myPosts, loading: false}); // here we are updating the posts state if redux state has updated value of likes
        }
    }
    render() {
        const {loading} = this.state;
        const {myPosts} = this.props
        console.log(this.state.posts);
        if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            return (<Redirect to='/signIn'/>);
        }
        if (loading) {
            return "loading..."
        }
        return (
            <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
                <h1>Posts</h1>
                {/* <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/> */}
                <div>
                    {this.state.posts.map(post => (
                            <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                                <PostItem myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                                    myTitle={this.state.title} editChange={this.onChange} editForm={this.formEditing} isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} removePost={this.removePost} {...post}/>
                            </Paper>
                        ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
   myPosts: state.post.posts, isEditingId: 
   state.post.isEditingId
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
    GetPosts: () => dispatch(GetPosts()),
    // specific.
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch(postLike(id)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

Comment: First, `componentWillRecieveProps` is considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code. Second, where are you setting `isLoading` as false?

Comment: `if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }`  it will show after posts finish .

Comment: after posts finish fetching.

Comment: The variable hasNewLike can never be false because it is initialized as true and the for loop only sets true...

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but all i want to know is how i can make componentWillRecieveProps work on the child component, or is the way im doing it already the way to do it.  making the changes you mentioned will not change anything.

Comment: You should use componentWillReceiveProps within the child component not in the parent

Comment: @jank thanks will make an answer

Answer (score 1):

I took @jank advice, and added the componentWillReceiveProps within the child component.

I was also missing `withRouter` in PostList, which without it the componentWillReciveProps will not work.

```
// without withRouter componentWillReceiveProps will not work like its supposed too.
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(PostList));
```

Updated code

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {DeletePost, postLike, UpdatePost,EditChange, GetPosts, getCount, DisableButton} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
import _ from 'lodash';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: '',
            posts:[],
            loading:true

        }
    } 

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.GetPosts();
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        let hasNewLike = true;
        if (prevState.posts && prevState.posts.length) {
            for (let index = 0; index < nextProps.myPosts.length; index++) {
                if (nextProps.myPosts[index].Likes.length !== prevState.posts[index].Likes.length) {
                    hasNewLike = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hasNewLike) {
            this.setState({posts: nextProps.myPosts, loading: false}); // here we are updating the posts state if redux state has updated value of likes
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }
    render(){
        const { posts, loading} = this.state;

        // console.log(this.props.posts)
        // console.log(this.props.ourLikes);
        if(loading){
            return "loading..."
        }
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.posts.map(post => (

              <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                <PostItem
                  myLikes={post.Likes.length} // right here
                  myTitle={this.state.title}
                  editChange={this.onChange}
                  editForm={this.formEditing}
                  isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id}
                  removePost={this.removePost}
                  {...post}

                />
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    myPosts: state.post.posts, 
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    GetPosts: () => dispatch(GetPosts()),
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
// without withRouter componentWillReceiveProps will not work like its supposed too.
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(PostList));
```

**Posts.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {GetPosts} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper:{
      margin: '20px 0px',
      padding:'20px'
    }
    , 
    wrapper:{
      padding:'0px 60px'
    }
}
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {

  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }

    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Posts);
```